# Java Parsing of a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
String unparsed = "[thing.1][thin2g]"
```

I want to turn it into

```
"thing.1"
"thin2g"
```

Been trying for a while with regex expressions but nothing.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

EDIT:

Tried:

```
String unparsed = "[thing.1][thin2g]"
String substring = unparsed.substring(1,unparsed.length - 1)
substring.replace("][","`")
String[] split = substring.split('`')
for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
{
   System.out.println(split[i])
}
```

But this seems kinda heavy, was looking for something more elegant

Comment: Show us what you tried. Use the `Pattern` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String unparsed = "[thing.1][thin2g]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(unparsed);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

My regex is not good. But it does parse the string into what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[\s*\w.*?\]
```

I never use regular expressions before but this one should work